# Typescript: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

Tags: typescript

So I have the following object:

```
{"1": {"name": "spencer", "number": "965756"}}, {"2": {"name": "mary", "number": "5346"}},  {"3": {"name": "john", "number": "1234"}}
```

This object is the result of a database query and I would like to convert this object into an array, using the `array.push()` method. This gives the error:

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
```

I was so sure that the error occurs, because `'{}'` would be the empty object in case the database query failed. So I did a check if the result object (`plainObjectResult`) was empty before converting it into an array. But the error stays and I don't have any idea why.

Here is the code:

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  number: string;
}

export interface PersonResults {
  [key: string]: Person;
}

// make the Realm database Result Object a plain "normal" object
const plainObjectResult: object = realmToPlainObject(queryResult);

const resultArray: PersonResults[] = [];

if (Object.keys(plainObjectResult).length > 0) {
  for (let person in plainObjectResult) {
    // person: 0, 1, 2, ...
    // plainObjectResult[person]: {"name": "spencer", "number": "965756"}
    resultArray.push({[person]: plainObjectResult[person]}); // above error occurs for "plainObjectResult[person]"
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **INVALID** `{"1": {"name": "spencer", "number": "965756"}}, {"2": {"name": "mary", "number": "5346"}},  {"3": {"name": "john", "number": "1234"}}`

It **should have been** `{ "1": { "name": "spencer", "number": "965756" }, "2": { "name": "mary", "number": "5346" }, "3": { "name": "john", "number": "1234" } }`

Try this

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  number: string;
}

export interface PersonResults {
  [key: string]: Person;
}

// make the Realm database Result Object a plain "normal" object
let plainObjectResult: any = { "1": { "name": "spencer", "number": "965756" }, "2": { "name": "mary", "number": "5346" }, "3": { "name": "john", "number": "1234" } };

const resultArray: PersonResults[] = [];

if (Object.keys(plainObjectResult).length > 0) {
  for (let person in plainObjectResult) {
    let id = '' + person;
    let obj:PersonResults  = {};
    obj[id] = plainObjectResult[person];
    resultArray.push(obj); // above error occurs for "plainObjectResult[person]"
  }
}

console.log('resultArray: ', resultArray)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I feel I don't really understand what you mean. Where should I do this?

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work because of setting plainObjectResult to any. Doing this, even my code in the question works. Setting plainObjectResult to object, your solution fails as well, unfortunately. Is it the right way to use any? Because I always thought that if using any, all the advantages of Typescript will be gone.

Comment: You can cast them back to the type you want to use. `object` and `any` types are already very similar to each other. The difference between using one of them shouldn't really be important.